# launchMode singleTop and onNewIntent()

Tags: android, android-activity, android-manifest, android-lifecycle

I have an activity I want to be launched only a single time from a giving task. I'm using launch mode = `singleTop`. What I expect from reading the docs is that I should get one `onCreate()`, and all subsequent starts of that activity (from the given task) should result in calls to `onNewIntent()`.

To test this, I start the activity 3 times in quick succession. What I see however is this,

1. instance 1: onCreate
2. instance 1: onResume
3. instance 1: onPause
4. instance 2: onCreate
5. instance 2: onResume
6. instance 2: onPause
7. instance 3: onCreate
8. instance 4: onResume

(By "instance" I mean different instance of my activity object).

Obviously this is not what I expected. Note that `onNewIntent()` is never called. What is going wrong?

Comment: Is your activity at the top of the stack when you launch a new instance?

Comment: Probably not yet. Like I said i'm calling `startActivity()` very rapidly. None of the activities have probably been created before I finish calling start on them.

Comment: Then you have your answer. onNewIntent() is called if the same activity is present on the top of the stack.

Comment: I have no idea what Android's definition of "on the top of the stack" is, or when that state is considered true in the system. I'd certainly expect the lifecycle to be setup such singleTop can't be easily circumvented by what I'm doing.

Comment: Read this: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack.html

Comment: @Quanturium, that's can't possibly be the way it works. the caller can't be expected to know that singleTop only works after the platform itself has passed some certain level in the lifecycle.

Comment: Calling startActivity() four times in a row is not something really common. Why are you doing this?

Comment: situation is that user accidentally double taps a button that starts an activity. sure, the button press can be protected, but i'd rather not burden the caller of the activity with having to do that. i agree it's an odd situation, but it's sort of unique usage scenario also.

Comment: Have you tried this? I'm not even sure that's possible to start multiple activities like this. However, If you trigger the startActivity() method (without delays) on the click of the button, the user can't trigger it a second time as the new activity will take the place of the previous activity.

Comment: @Quanturium i wish that was true, but it isn't. there is a delay between pressing the button and the next activity coming into the foreground.